# Show fields for a Lucene/Elasticsearch index

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Is there a way to get Lucene/Elasticsearch to just show what fields have been indexed in a given index?  I'm trying to figure out whether certain fields have been indexed properly as a result of configuration options, but I have no idea how to make that determination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the mappings for a specific index and type via a call to:

```
http://localhost:9200/index/type/_mapping
```

Anything indexed should have an entry there.

Answer (score 0):

See also analyze API to see how text is broken into terms.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html