# How to get list of all field names in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been trying to get all the field names in my ElasticSearch database dynamically so I can input them into a GUI drop down search box.

`{

     "odd": ["three", "five", "nine"],

     "even": ["two", "four", "six"],

     "prime": ["seven", "thirteen", "seventeen"]

}`

Is there a way to obtain the field names : odd, even and prime
Such that I can enter them into a Jcombobox in the user interface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show fields for a Lucene/Elasticsearch index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165537/show-fields-for-a-lucene-elasticsearch-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GetMappingsResponse res = null; //Get entire mapping of elasticsearch
    try {
        res = client.admin().indices().getMappings(new GetMappingsRequest().indices("foo").types("bar")).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ImmutableOpenMap<String, MappingMetaData> mapping = res.mappings().get("foo");
    String[] FieldNames = new String[20];
    String[] FieldNameArray;

    for (ObjectObjectCursor<String, MappingMetaData> c : mapping) {
        FieldNames[0] = c.value.source().toString(); //grabs and stores the mapping
    }
    String dirtyField = FieldNames[0];
    List<String> badWords = Arrays.asList(  "foo"); //here i parse the entire mapping to just obtain the field names

    for ( String badWord : badWords ) {  //filters the mapping so we can capture only the added metadata
        dirtyField = dirtyField.replaceAll("" + badWord + "", "");
    }
    String  cleanField = dirtyField.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]"," "); 

    FieldNameArray = cleanField.split("\\s+"); //splits the string into an array of individual words
    System.out.println("Updated Field Name Array");
    return FieldNameArray;
```

It's pretty ugly, but this is how i ended up resolving the issue and grabbing just the field names.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery...

```
//...Get data

var hits  = body.hits.hits;
$.each(hits, function(index, value){
  var sources = hits[index]._source;
  $.each(sources, function(i, j){//i is the name of the field and j is the value
    //Use data
  });
});
```